# AngularJS + Django Rest Framework - X-CSRFToken not being set as header

Tags: angularjs, django, rest, cookies, django-rest-framework

I currently have a Django Rest Framework backend running on a computer at home, and an AngularJS frontend, both on different `ips`. When I make a request to `rest-auth/login`, it returns a Set-Cookie header with a session id, and a csrftoken, http only is **not** true.

```
Set-Cookie:csrftoken=SOMECSRFTOKENHERE; expires=Fri, 09-Jun-2017 01:25:16 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
```

On any subsequent post requests, or get request, I noticed I have a header called `Cookie` which looks like this:

```
csrftoken=SOMECSRFTOKENHERE; sessionid=SOMESESSIONIDHERE
```

and get this response from the server:
`CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect`

This seems to be the case when I have `withCredentials` set to true.

I noticed that when I run `console.log($cookies.csrftoken)`, it logs undefined. I know that according to the angular docs that for xsrf headers: *The header will not be set for cross-domain requests.* But, the cookie is not being stored, however, it is being sent as a request cookie, which I have no access to.

How can I gain access to it and is there anyway I can use the `X-CSRFToken` header for cross domain requests?

I've looked at other posts on here, and have found no solution that works.

Current config:

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
}]);
```

Update:

I added an interceptor to add the `x-csrftoken` header; however, I still have no access to the cookie `csrftoken`.

```
.factory('csrfInterceptor',['$cookies', function($cookies){
    var csrfInterceptor =  {
        request: function(config) {
            if(config.method == 'POST'){
                //config.headers['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies.csrftoken;
            }
            return config;
        }
    };
    return csrfInterceptor;
}])
```

The value of `$cookies.csrftoken` still returns undefined, however, I'm still not sure how to get access to that value.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I'll answer anyway given I'm having the same issue. You actually aren't using $cookie correctly it's $cookie.get("csrftoken"); not $cookie.csrftoken